# NullPointerException getting a TextView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview, nullpointerexception

I am creating an extremely simple Android application to serve as a proof of concept and a reference for an application I will create in the future.

My goal is to create a `ListView`, each item containing a `TextView` and a `Button` that, when pressed, makes a `Toast` pop up displaying the content of the `TextView`.

Here is my code and xml:

**main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainListView1"/> 

</LinearLayout>
```

**entry.XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:id="@+id/entryLayout"
>

<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/entryTextView1"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="25sp"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
    android:id="@+id/entryImageButton"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.Class**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
/* Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Set main.xml as user interface layout
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    String[] companies = new String[] { "Test1", "Test2", "Test3",
        "Test4", "Test4", "Test6", "Test7", "Test8", "Test9", "Test10"};

    ArrayList<LinearLayout> views =  new ArrayList<LinearLayout>();
    for(int x=0; x!= companies.length-1; x++){

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.entryLayout);
        TextView text = (TextView) layout.getChildAt(0);
        text.setText(companies[x]);
        ImageButton button = (ImageButton) layout.getChildAt(1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) v.getParent();
                TextView view = (TextView) layout.getChildAt(0);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,view.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });
        views.add(layout);
    }


    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainListView1);
    for(LinearLayout layout: views){
        listView.addView(layout);
    }

}
```

I get an Kin the line

```
TextView text = (TextView) layout.getChildAt(0);
```

And for the life of me I can't figure out why. This is likely due to my lack of knowledge to how certain functions in the API work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your immediate issue is that `findViewById` looks in the `layout` you've inflated with `setContentView()` and since the `Views` you are trying to inflate aren't in that `layout`, they return `null`.

So this line returns null

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.entryLayout);
```

which causes a `NPE` at this line as you've noticed

```
TextView text = (TextView) layout.getChildAt(0);
```

because `layout` is `null`.

### **The bigger issue**

is the way you are going about using your `ListView`. Since you want to use a custom `layout` for the rows, you should be using a custom `Adapter` and inflate the appropriate `layout` there . You can then utilize `Adapter`'s `getView()` method to set the data in each row as needed.

[This tutorial](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vogella.com%2Ftutorials%2FAndroidListView%2Farticle.html&ei=jZ6AVJ2pFIWdygSp8IHADw&usg=AFQjCNEmKxSOQWTEdnIteMT1duTBuc2Xsg&sig2=1i1CkgtBqzesnzdiau5qzg&bvm=bv.80642063,d.aWw) can help you get started on that.

You also may want to watch [Google I/O World of ListView](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70)

[ListView Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)

Comment: I assumed I had been neglecting a bigger concept. Thanks I'll look into this